# Is this a good solution to cycling through images?

Tags: android

I came up with a re-usable "BitmapHelper" class to help my app cycle through full-screen images.
I did this because the UI thread needs to update the ImageView and I don't want to use globals in my Activity to pass in the Bitmap and ImageView references.

The code below works but I observe **Low Memory: No more background processes** which has me worried about a memory leak

**The BitmapHelper class:**

```
public class BitmapHelper
{
    //member variables
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Activity mActivity;


    //constructor requires Activity and ImageView to work on
    // requiring the ImageView here implies that one BitmapHelper is used per ImageView
    public BitmapHelper(Activity activity, ImageView imageview)
    {
        mActivity = activity;
        mImageView = imageview;
    }


    //loadImageAsset(name of asset, i.e. "image.png")
    public void loadImageAsset(String assetfilename)
    {
        boolean bError = false;

        try
        {
            mBitmap = getBitmapFromAsset(assetfilename);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bError = true;
        }

        //assign Bitmap to Imageview
        //NOTE!! this must be done in the UI thread or it's
        //       crash time when executed from another thread
        if (bError == false)
        {
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    //getBitmapFromAsset(name of asset, i.e. "image.png")
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String assetfilename) throws IOException
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = mActivity.getAssets();

        InputStream istr = assetManager.open(assetfilename);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

**The Activity:**

```
public class myActivity extends Activity
{
    //member variables
    private String mFilenames[];
    private int mFilenameIndex;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Timer mTimerSeconds;
    private int mIntIdleSeconds;
    private BitmapHelper mBitmapHelper;

    //for logging
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.standby);

        //get references to UI components
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.standby_imageview_adtop);

        //image slideshow
        mFilenames = new String[]{"pic1.png","pic2.png", "pic3.png"};
        mFilenameIndex = 0;
        mBitmapHelper = new BitmapHelper(this, mImageView);
        mBitmapHelper.loadImageAsset(mFilenames[mFilenameIndex]);

        //timer
        startSlideshowTimer();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        if (mTimerSeconds != null)
        {
            mTimerSeconds.cancel();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }



    /**
     * timer functions
     */

    //start the slideshow timer
    public void startSlideshowTimer()
    {

        //initialize idle counter
        mIntIdleSeconds=0;

        //create timer to tick every second
        mTimerSeconds = new Timer();
        mTimerSeconds.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                timerSecondsCounter();
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }


    //called every second to count idle time and to update clock on Welcome screen
    private void timerSecondsCounter()
    {

        mIntIdleSeconds++;

        if (mIntIdleSeconds == Constants.MAX_AD_TIME_SECONDS)
        {
            //cycle to next image
            mFilenameIndex++;
            if (mFilenameIndex == mFilenames.length)
            {
                mFilenameIndex=0;
            }

            mBitmapHelper.loadImageAsset(mFilenames[mFilenameIndex]);

            //reset counter
            mIntIdleSeconds=0;
        }

    }//end of: timerSecondsCounter()

}
```

for testing, I set **Constants.MAX_AD_TIME_SECONDS = 1** and the app cycles through an image every second. It's cool to watch but the ActivityManager is shutting down other processes.

am I doing it wrong or right ?

note: the images are about 130KB to 280KB big

---

EDIT: as suggested I have updated my BitmapHelper class to pre-load the images. See the following ...

```
public class BitmapHelper
{
    //member variables
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Activity mActivity;

    private Map<String,Bitmap> mBitHashmap;


    //constructor requires Activity and ImageView to work on
    // requiring the ImageView here implies that one BitmapHelper is used per ImageView
    public BitmapHelper(Activity activity, ImageView imageview)
    {
        mActivity = activity;
        mImageView = imageview;
        mBitHashmap = new HashMap<String,Bitmap>();
    }


    //loadAndShowImageAsset(name of asset, i.e. "image.png")
    //NOTE: avoid doing too many of these, otherwise the heap is used-up
    //      and the ActivityManager starts closing down background activities
    public void loadAndShowImageAsset(String assetfilename)
    {
        boolean bError = false;

        try
        {
            mBitmap = getBitmapFromAsset(assetfilename);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bError = true;
        }

        //assign Bitmap to Imageview
        //NOTE!! this must be done in the UI thread or it's
        //       crash time when executed from another thread
        if (bError == false)
        {
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    //putImageInBuffer(name of asset, i.e. "image.png")
    public void putImageInBuffer(String assetfilename)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromAsset(assetfilename);
            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                mBitHashmap.put(assetfilename, bitmap);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    //showImageInBuffer(name of asset, i.e. "image.png")
    //NOTE: pre-load all the images to memory and then use this to set the
    //      image in the ImageView. This is the heap-friendly way to do it.
    public void showImageInBuffer(String assetfilename)
    {
        mBitmap = mBitHashmap.get(assetfilename);

        if (mBitmap != null)
        {
            //assign Bitmap to Imageview
            //NOTE!! this must be done in the UI thread or it's
            //       crash time when executed from another thread
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    //getBitmapFromAsset(name of asset, i.e. "image.png")
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String assetfilename) throws IOException
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = mActivity.getAssets();

        InputStream istr = assetManager.open(assetfilename);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

Instead of using "loadImageAsset(), I now use showImageInBuffer() to display the image on the UI.
I've been testing this implementation for 15mins (cycling through images every second) and no nasty "Low Memory" messages have been witnessed.

Comment: try not to load each image using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);` **every time**.  store a reference to them in something like a `SoftReference`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that even though you have only a few images, a new image gets loaded into the heap every second and therefore memory is constantly consumed.

The proper way to do this is to load the pictures once. You may simply load all the pictures and store refernces to them in a `Map`. Later when you need to show a picture, you won't have to load it again.

You may also use a `WeakHashMap` if you have a lot of pictures. This way references to pictures will be there only when they are used by some `View`. As soon as the picture is not in the `View`, it will be available for garbage collection.

Comment: I used Map in my updated solution. Judging from the following sample code Map and WeakHashMap are easily interchangeable ... http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-use-java-weakhashmap-class-example

Comment: Yes, `Map` is a generic interface which has different implementations. So you can use any of them that suits your needs. I suggested WeakHashMap because it enables garbage collector to reclaim the images when they are no longer used, but you may use other implementations, of course. When you work with an interface and not with the actual implementations, it is very easy to switch them.

Comment: I haven't used WeakHashMap before - to differentiate their use are the following use cases appropriate? 1) use Map when images are required to be available for the life of the Activity  2) use WeakHashMap when images don't need to be available 100% of the time, for example, when a user is casually scrolling through a ListView of images or Gallery of downloaded images.

Comment: Well, technically when you use `WeakHashMap`, it is still a particular implementation of a Map. So I assume in the case 1) you mean a "regular" implementation like `HashMap`. Yes, your cases are correct, when you use `WeakHashMap`, you allow GC to save some heap when the object is unused, but you'll have to create this object again if you need it later and GC has collected it.

Comment: In case 1) I did indeed mean HashMap. Thanks for taking the time to help me out :cheer: